# Repairing Broken Slider Inside Bosch Dishwasher

Tags: dishwasher

The left-hand drawer slide that holds the upper rack of my circa 2003 Bosch dishwasher has completely broken off. It looks like it was spot-welded to the stainless interior in two places, and both welds have failed.

The rear weld failed a few weeks ago, and I attempted to fix it with JB Weld, but that didn't even hold for a single washing. The front weld broke yesterday and we're now stuck with a single-rack dishwasher.

I don't have access to a welder, which is probably a good thing because I would probably end up attempting to weld the slider back on, and end up melting the plastic shell on the outside of the dishwasher. I assume it has a plastic exterior shell.

Should I drill the side walls and screw the slider back in place? I assume I can seal the screw holes relatively well, I saw someone mention in another thread  that red RTV Silicone Sealant works for dishwashers. However, I would still be worried that about puncturing any exterior plastic shell with the drill or screws. I should probably pull it out and take a look.

Anyway, I guess I'm just looking for ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: I'm confused, you say it has a stainless interior as the welds have failed, but you then say you are concerned about drilling the plastic. I would, if it is worth fixing, dismantle it and use a spot-welder to re-fix the slide. That way there are no holes to seal.

Comment: I guess I just assumed there was a double wall. I pulled it out just now and it's just a single wall with a bunch of sound-deadening on it.

Comment: That now sounds like every dishwasher I have opened.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exterior shell with most dishwashers. They have a plastic or steel cabinet with exterior reinforcing ribs surrounded by a layer of sound insulation, which can be easily removed.

You certainly could drill and screw the repair as long as you seal it well, either with RTV or something less reliant on the bond, such as a neoprene washer.

Answer (score -1):

Someone suggested a strong magnet. I used two thin magnets from a pc hard drive and boom holds it in place perfectly

Comment: You're holding up the top rack of a dishwasher with a stainless steel tub with a _magnet_? This I gotta see. Your dishes must all be foam.

Comment: "*... and boom holds it in place perfectly*". What is "boom" and where do you buy it? Is it dishwasher safe?